chatGPTの文字表示が遅い。
私はエンジニアではないのですが、プログラマの皆さんの知識が必要なのでお貸しください。
質問本文：
ChatGPTを利用しているのですが、回答が順番に文字として表示されるのが遅く感じられて少し不快です(仕様なのかな？)。この速度を速くする方法があれば知りたいと思っています。おそらく、JavaScriptの設定を変更すれば改善できるのではないかと考えていますが、詳しい知識がありません。もしこの問題を解決する方法をご存知の方がいれば、ぜひ教えていただけないでしょうか？

ChatGPTの種類は何でしょうか？何か他のものと比べて「遅く感じられて少し不快です」なのでしょうか？
